# How to move range values to Top after filtering using vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

How to move range values to top after filtering using vba macro as per the requirement, I have filtered all defects by severity then filter it with lob, but my requirement all JIRA in Column A should be on top.

[image: screenshot]

I am not getting how to move it to top of all JIRA in column A.appreciate help here.

note: after the move severity should not be altered ie. all JIRA defect should be filtered with severity. as per the screen shot attached

```
Sub moverange()
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set MR = Range("A2:A" & lRow)
MR.Select
For Each cell In MR
'If cell.Value = "Jira" Then Selection.EntireRow.Cut Shift:=xlUp
 If cell.Value = "Jira" Then
 Selection.Cut
'Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp
End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: spend some time with Table functionality. In your raw data, select the Insert ribbon and click on Table. It will give you a lot of powerful filtering and sorting capabilities to look at your data.

Comment: For your VBA, read up on [Range.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) instead of cutting and pasting.

Comment: @ OldUgly : the sheet is dynamic one, everytime it pull defects from different alm and Jira. what i had in my mind was just click the button and everything should go . filter and option i was able to do it. 

issue happened, when sorted the row A in alphabetical order, JIRA went in between, So requirement was to show all JIRA defects on top rest on the bottom.

appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple helper-column which is `0` for "Jira" and `1` for not "Jira" (or `true` `false` or whatever) and then sort it with the helper column as first criteria...

Or if you do not want to change the order (and just get "Jira" at top) use in helper column (start in row 2):

```
=ROW()+1000*(A2<>"Jira")
```

and then just sort by the helper column.
This way the order stays the same, except that "Jira" comes first and everything else later on.

You also can use a special sort order if the old order doesn't matter with custom sort:

```
Sort by: Column A
Sort on: Values
Order:   Custom List...
```

A new Window pops up and there you simply need to enter "Jira" (without quotes) in the right box and hit OK. This way it will order like normal, but "Jira" will come first.

To do it via VBA you can do it whith this code:

```
Sub moverange()
  Dim SRange As Range
  With ActiveSheet.Sort
    Set SRange = .Parent.Range("A2", .Parent.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add SRange, 0, 1, "Jira", 0
    .SetRange SRange.EntireRow
    .Apply
  End With
End Sub
```

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: thanks a ton for your efforts in helping here, it does pick all JIRA and puts in on top but only thing is it clears the sort, i am sure will get a chance to use your logic .thanks again.:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub MoveRange()        
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim SortArr1 As Variant, SortArr2 As Variant

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set MyRange = Range("A1:G" & LastRow)     '-->change "G" to any other column if needed

    'setting sort order for Column "E"
    SortArr1 = Array("high", "medium", "low")
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=SortArr1

    'sorting Column "E"
    MyRange.Sort Key1:=Range("E1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:= _
        False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount

    'setting sort order for Column "A"
    SortArr2 = Array("jira")
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=SortArr2

    'sorting Column "A"
    MyRange.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:= _
        False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
End Sub
```

Here I've assumed that your data is till Column`G`.
Above code sorts the data two times. First on  Column `E` to sort data as per severity and then on Column `A`.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked perfectly as i wanted. it did not clear the severity filter and JIRA on top and  for others LOB(column) i can see severity filters applied.